# Failed to decode downloaded font: file:///Local directory/fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfonte0a5-2.html?v=4.3.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I am unable to get Graphic icons on a template. It shows me square boxes. and the error comes in console is as below

Failed to decode downloaded font: file:///Local Directory/fonts/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfonte0a5-2.html?v=4.3.0

Failed to decode downloaded font: file:///Local Directory/fonts/fontello/font/fontello3904-2.html?46462644

Please help me to solve this. This files are being downloaded and put on the right path, the issue is for decoding it.

regards

Answer (score 0):

downgrade to version 3.3.4, I think that is a bug on bootstrap 3.3.5.
Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur response.
But I found the issue, as soon as I deleted cache and removed the .html files, and again downloaed it. It was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this issue, as I just clean the cache, removed the .html file which was downloaded with template, and again downloaded the whole template.

Than opening the index.html file works for me.